# Nested Loop Optimization in OpenMP

Tags: fortran, openmp

I can't get the output result correct once applied openMP, is it anywhere get this right?

```
!$OMP PARALLEL DO SHARED(outmtresult,inpa,inpb,dynindexlist) PRIVATE(i,j) REDUCTION(+:outcountb)

do i=1,size1  
  do j=1, size1
    outcountb = outcountb + 1
    outmtresult(j) = tan(inpa(j) + inpb(j)) + alpha1 + dynindexlist(i) 
  enddo
enddo

!$OMP END PARALLEL DO
```

Comment: Include fully conpilable exampe, what it should print and what it prints instead. I have no clue what your sample is about.

Comment: I meant compilable example, some working code which we can understand and which we can try.

Comment: I have no clue what you are trying to achieve with that code. Please extend your question after reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)! And don't duplicate your questions---what is the difference to [your old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28757570/double-loop-in-openmp)?

Answer (score 0):

Just swap your loops and everything will be fine:

```
!$OMP PARALLEL DO SHARED(outmtresult,inpa,inpb,dynindexlist) PRIVATE(i,j) REDUCTION(+:outcountb)

do j=1,size1        ! <-- Swap i and
  do i=1, size1     !       j here
    outcountb = outcountb + 1
    outmtresult(j) = tan(inpa(j) + inpb(j)) + alpha1 + dynindexlist(i) 
  enddo
enddo

!$OMP END PARALLEL DO
```

In your example, multiple threads write into the same memory address `outmtresult(j)` since you parallelize the `do i` loop.

By swapping the loops, you parallelize over `do j` and you will not write
at the same destination with multiple concurrent threads.